# Is it possible to see how many views a YouTube video got in a given year, using YouTube Data API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Like for example, for the infamous zoo video, the rick roll or literally any other video.
Basically I'm making a website for YouTube analytics, and am thinking to add a feature so that you can search a video and it'll show you a graph of number of views for each year between 2010 and 2020, showing which year the video actually peaked and stuff like that.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Unfortunately, YouTube Data API does not provide the info you're looking for.

Comment: ah thought so....wouldve been a  good feature...do u know any other sites that store data like that so maybe i can scrap it from them?

Comment: @GazP as SO user "stvar" mentioned, YouTube Data API does not have such feature, however, try to research about google trendings; like this [example](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?gprop=youtube&q=%2Fm%2F0dnf6m) - thought, it *might* differ to your objectives, but, it's interesting, nonetheless.

Comment: Wow macro! this is not exaclty what i wanted, but i don't mind it u know i just need to find a way to scrap it, i  don't think they have any api for google trends